# Can I use } else { without using an "if" statement?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to animate some buttons in an app, when you click on a larger one, three smaller one's come out, however, the larger one does not change it's state, if it did I would set it to basically be

if larger one changes state/image (on or off)
then the smaller one's come out.

The problem is when I want the smaller one's to go back in. I can't use the else statement to set the smaller buttons location.

EDIT:

```
@IBAction func rainBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.heavyThunderBtn.center = self.heavyThunderCenter
        self.lightRainBtn.center = self.lightRainCenter
        self.rainOnRoofBtn.center = self.rainOnRoofCenter

    })
} else {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    heavyThunderBtn.center = rainBtn.center
    lightRainBtn.center = rainBtn.center
    rainOnRoofBtn.center = rainBtn.center

})
```

}

Comment: provide your code?

Comment: What? I am completely lost with what you are trying to do. But no, you can’t use `else` without `if` (or at least `guard`). Come out of what? Go back in what? You may have an image in your head of what you want to happen. But the description you have given is fairly ambiguous. Can you show a screenshot of what you want? Or perhaps paste some code to show what you tried?

Comment: I added the code. Everything past that first animation won't work, which is when the heavyThunderBtn, lightRainBtn, and rainOnRoofBtn won't return to being under the rainBtn.

Comment: What is your not else condition. Else only works with a condition. When do you want to the first block of code to be run? If xyz then do somethingA else do somethingB.

Comment: When the rain button is pressed, it runs that first block, but if it's pressed again, the second block.

Comment: That has nothing to do with an if-else statement. You just simply need to store the count of the button presses and act according to that number in your `IBAction`.

Answer (score 2):

No, however...

### Negate your condition

You can easily convert this block of code

```
if condition {
    print("Condition is true")
} else {
    print("Condition is false")
}
```

to this one

```
if !condition {
    print("Condition is false")
}
```

### guard

Alternatively you can use the `guard` construct, but you'll need to **break** the flow inside the `else`.

```
guard condition else {
    print("Condition is false")
    return
}
```